# Creating a BINGO Game

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to create a BINGO game using letters instead of numbers.  I am breaking down the javascript code. Before I do random letters, I want the "square0" to display a letter (for example: "a") However, the letter "a" is not displaying.  I would appreciate any suggestions. This is what I have:

HTML:

```
<table class="bingo">
    <tr>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>I</th>
        <th>N</th>
        <th>G</th>
        <th>O</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square0"></td>
        <td id="square1"></td>
        <td id="square2"></td>
        <td id="square3"></td>
        <td id="square4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square5"></td>
        <td id="square6"></td>
        <td id="square7"></td>
        <td id="square8"></td>
        <td id="square9"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square10"></td>
        <td id="square11"></td>
        <td id="free">Free</td>
        <td id="square13"></td>
        <td id="square14"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="square15"></td>
        <td id="square16"></td>
        <td id="square17"></td>
        <td id="square18"></td>
        <td id="square19"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td id="square20"></td>
        <td id="square21"></td>
        <td id="square22"></td>
        <td id="square23"></td>
        <td id="square24"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}

window.onload = function () {
    document.$("square0").innerHTML = "a";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RE006/1g4mdqgo/

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown in the question doesn't work because you need to reference your get element shortcut function as `$()` or `window.$()`, *not* as `document.$()`.

```
window.onload = function () {
    $("square0").innerHTML = "a";
    // OR window.$("square0").innerHTML = "a";
}
```

Your fiddle doesn't work because:

- You haven't included the definition of your `$()` function
- You have tried to set `window.onload =` *inside* the default onload handler that jsfiddle provides for you, which means that by the time you try to create your own onload handler the onload event has already occurred. Have a look on the left under the Frameworks & Extensions heading: there's a dropdown that says `"onLoad"`, which you should change to `"No wrap - in <head>"` (or `"No wrap - in <body>"`).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1g4mdqgo/4/

Answer (score 0):

Just updated the fiddle, which was missing the function.

```
var $ = function (id)     {
 return document.getElementById(id);
}

window.onload = { $("square0").innerHTML = "a"; }
```

This keeps the function separate to calling it since I presume you plan to call it multiple times.

The 'document' was already part of the function so it was not needed when calling window.onload, effectively your code was doing a `document.document.getElementById`.

The term 'function()' is not needed inside the `onload` when calling the variable `$` which executes the function call itself. See [functions as expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp)

nnnnnn gave a working answer also including the onload explanation for jfiddle (onload is a jsfiddle option under Frameworks on the left menu).

Comment: The `function()` part is definitely needed.

Comment: Hi Mousey:

You mentioned that the function() is not needed in side the onload.  I am a little confuse why did they add it here?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onload_dom

Comment: function() is needed once, which is when the variable is used to create an anonymous function.

Comment: sorry hit Enter too soon- function() is needed *once* - you can *either* use it when creating `$` as an anonymous function, *or* in  `onload` as *nnnnnn* did. What `var $ = function (id) { return document.getElementById(id); }` means is that wherever you put `$` it will interpret is as `function (id)  {.. etc}.` nnnnnn's code uses `function()` once too, but your uses it *twice*. The w3schools example has no variable,  `function()` appears once. [Equivalent w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_function_expression) to your code (Functions as Expressions link)